# My first game: Python using pygame vs. Java using lwjgl?

Tags: java, python, pygame, lwjgl

My game would be a simple 2D tower defense type game. It should have some animations and sounds. I've only learned Java so this seems like a huge plus for choosing that option. But I'm fairly new to programming so i suppose it wont be a huge problem to switch.

From my limited research, either Python using pygame or Java using lwjgl seems to be best suited for my kind of game.

What are your thoughts? Benefits of one over the other? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Java + LWJGL is very low level and you'll have to write a lot of the sound and animation code yourself. A better choice would be Java + Slick2D (a 2d library on top of LWJGL). You can find it at http://slick.cokeandcode.com

Answer (score 5):

A benefit from Pygame for the kind of game you want to do is the [Python Pygame Tower Defense project](http://www.pygame.org/project-Python+PyGame+Tower+Defence-1296-.html) that could be a pretty good tutorial for what you want to do, isn't it ?